# Using custom trained Keras model with Sagemaker endpoint results in "Session was not created with a graph before Run()" error while prediction

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, keras, amazon-sagemaker

I have a trained a BERT text classification model using keras on spam vs ham dataset. I have deployed the model and got a Sagemaker endpoint. I want to use it for any prediction.

I am using a `ml.t2.medium` Sagemaker instance and my tensorflow version is `2.6.2` in the Sagemaker notebook

I am getting an error while using the Sagemaker endpoint for prediction. The error is `Session was not created with a graph before Run()`

This is my code for training the classifier

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_text as text


# In[2]:


import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("spam.csv")
df.head(5)


# In[3]:


df.groupby('Category').describe()


# In[4]:


df['Category'].value_counts()


# In[5]:


df_spam = df[df['Category']=='spam']
df_spam.shape


# In[6]:


df_ham = df[df['Category']=='ham']
df_ham.shape


# In[7]:


df_ham_downsampled = df_ham.sample(df_spam.shape[0])
df_ham_downsampled.shape


# In[8]:


df_balanced = pd.concat([df_ham_downsampled, df_spam])
df_balanced.shape


# In[9]:


df_balanced['Category'].value_counts()


# In[10]:


df_balanced['spam']=df_balanced['Category'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x=='spam' else 0)
df_balanced.sample(5)


# In[11]:


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_balanced['Message'],df_balanced['spam'], stratify=df_balanced['spam'])


# In[12]:


bert_preprocess = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3")
bert_encoder = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/4")


# In[13]:


def get_sentence_embeding(sentences):
    preprocessed_text = bert_preprocess(sentences)
    return bert_encoder(preprocessed_text)['pooled_output']

get_sentence_embeding([
    "500$ discount. hurry up", 
    "Bhavin, are you up for a volleybal game tomorrow?"]
)


# In[14]:


# Bert layers
text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
preprocessed_text = bert_preprocess(text_input)
outputs = bert_encoder(preprocessed_text)

# Neural network layers
l = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1, name="dropout")(outputs['pooled_output'])
l = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name="output")(l)

# Use inputs and outputs to construct a final model
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input], outputs = [l])


# In[15]:


model.summary()


# In[16]:


METRICS = [
      tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
      tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
      tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall')
]

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=METRICS)


# In[17]:


model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1)
```

AND THIS PART IS USED FOR DEPLOYING THE MODEL

```
# In[18]:


model.save('saved_model/28dec1') 


# In[3]:


model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model/28dec1')

model.predict(["who is the spammer on here"])

array([[0.08218178]], dtype=float32)

# Check its architecture
model.summary()


# In[18]:


tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
print("pass")


# In[5]:


def convert_h5_to_aws(loaded_model):
    """
    given a pre-trained keras model, this function converts it to a TF protobuf format
    and saves it in the file structure which aws expects
    """  
    from tensorflow.python.saved_model import builder
    from tensorflow.python.saved_model.signature_def_utils import predict_signature_def
    from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants
    
    # This is the file structure which AWS expects. Cannot be changed. 
    model_version = '1'
    export_dir = 'export/Servo/' + model_version
    
    # Build the Protocol Buffer SavedModel at 'export_dir'
    builder = builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)
    
    # Create prediction signature to be used by TensorFlow Serving Predict API
    signature = predict_signature_def(
        inputs={"inputs": loaded_model.input}, outputs={"score": loaded_model.output})
    
    from keras import backend as K
    with K.get_session() as sess:
        # Save the meta graph and variables
        builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
            sess=sess, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING], signature_def_map={"serving_default": signature})
        builder.save()
    
    #create a tarball/tar file and zip it
    import tarfile
    with tarfile.open('model.tar.gz', mode='w:gz') as archive:
        archive.add('export', recursive=True)
        
convert_h5_to_aws(model)


# In[3]:


import sagemaker

sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
inputs = sagemaker_session.upload_data(path='model.tar.gz', key_prefix='model')


# In[7]:


# where did it upload to?
print("Bucket name is:")
sagemaker_session.default_bucket()


# In[9]:


import boto3, re
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

# the (default) IAM role you created when creating this notebook
role = get_execution_role()

# Create a Sagemaker model (see AWS console>SageMaker>Models)
from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowModel
sagemaker_model = TensorFlowModel(model_data = 's3://' + sagemaker_session.default_bucket() + '/model/model.tar.gz',
                                  role = role,
                                  framework_version = '1.12',
                                  entry_point = 'train.py')


# In[10]:


# Deploy a SageMaker to an endpoint
predictor = sagemaker_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                                   instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')


# In[5]:


import numpy as np
   
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowModel

endpoint = 'sagemaker-tensorflow-serving-2021-10-28-11-18-34-001' #get endpoint name from SageMaker > endpoints

predictor=sagemaker.tensorflow.model.TensorFlowPredictor(endpoint, sagemaker_session)
# .predict send the data to our endpoint
#data = np.asarray(["what the shit"]) #<-- update this to have inputs for your model
predictor.predict(["this is not a spam"])
```

And I am getting this error

```
ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "{ "error": "Session was not created with a graph before Run()!" }
```

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving model as h5 use below method.

> model.save("export/Servo/1/")
> for some reason it expects exact format. Also, please remove if any hidden file is there in this folder.

This will save the model already in protobuf format.